# reset route instead of adding a new route to the current one

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to create a router navigation and prevent 404 errors. When manipulating a valid URL to an invalid one the next router link won't work anymore. I created a working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/8l60y06pmj

To see the problem do the following steps:

- Click on the link navigating to page 2
- change the url `https://8l60y06pmj.codesandbox.io/#/pageTwo` to `https://8l60y06pmj.codesandbox.io/#/pageTwo/whateverYouLike`
- Click on the link navigating to page 3

Now you should have the following URL

`https://8l60y06pmj.codesandbox.io/#/pageTwo/pageThree`

but the correct URL should be

`https://8l60y06pmj.codesandbox.io/#/pageThree`

You can reset this behaviour by clicking on the link navigating to the home view.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `NavbarComponent.vue`, you need to add a `/` to both of the page links; it should look something like this after the changes.

```
<router-link to="/pageTwo">Page Two</router-link> | 
<router-link to="/pageThree">Page Three</router-link>
```

Without that slash, you aren't actually telling Vue Router to send the user to a new page.

[Here's a working version of your CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vmzj5r2ywl).